# How to improve socket performance for huge amount of short-sized messages in java?

Tags: java, sockets

I use java.net.Socket and java.io.InputStream classes (JDK 8) to receive about 10-50 Megabytes per second. 
My application is a server which receives data from a client.

It works very well if a client send at least several Kilobytes for a single socket.write operation. However, when the client tries to write data with a message size less than 100 bytes I have not more than 5-10 Megabytes per second. I think it is connected with tcp delaying on reading data.

Is there any way to improve performance? Only receiving data is needed. Can a network driver bufferize input?

Comment: The only place to solve this is the sending end.

Comment: Does it really a single solution? Does Tcp block the sender until I read data?

Comment: Many small packets introduce a lot of overhead, both in header bytes and all the switching mechanisms needed to deliver them to the receiver. TCP should automatically delay sending of small packets, giving a chance to the sender to "load up" the packet with further data before it departs from the sending node.

Comment: I understand it, but in a case 200 bytes per a message speed still low.

Comment: And situation is the same when I run both a client and a server on the same machine.